# Java if statement that only runs when in debug mode

Tags: java

I have an if statement that is only evaluated when in debug mode

MyStuff class (the "main" class);

```
package com.lorenjz.jambii;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyStuff {

   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
      ControlGack gack = new ControlGack();
      gack.setVisible(true);
      new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            MainWindow mW = new MainWindow();
            mW.run();
        }}.start();
      Client c = new Client();
      try {
         c.run(null);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

A window that extracts RGB color averages for the screen that it resides in:

```
package com.lorenjz.jambii;

import java.awt.AWTException;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ComponentListener, Runnable{

    static int currentPixel;
    static int red;
    static int blue;
    static int green;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static JPanel panel;
    static myPrefs mP;
    static Boolean serverState = false;

    public static class Globals{
        static int screenWidth = 1366;
        static int screenHeight = 768;
        static int RedforSend = 0;
    }

    public void run() {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          try {
             MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
             frame.addComponentListener(frame);
             frame.setLocation(mP.getMWXPos(), mP.getMWYPos());
             frame.setVisible(true);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }});
       while (true){
          Robot robot;
          try {
             robot = new Robot();
             BufferedImage screenShot =
                robot.createScreenCapture(
                   new Rectangle(
                      new Dimension( Globals.screenWidth,Globals.screenHeight )));
             for (int xPosition = 0; xPosition < Globals.screenWidth; xPosition ++) {
                for (int yPosition = 0; yPosition < Globals.screenHeight; yPosition++){
                   currentPixel = screenShot.getRGB(xPosition, yPosition);
                   red = red +(int) (255 & (currentPixel >> 16));
                   green = green + (int) (255 & (currentPixel >> 8));
                   blue = blue + (int) (255 & (currentPixel));
                }
             }
             int numberOfSidePixels = Globals.screenWidth * Globals.screenHeight;
             red = red /numberOfSidePixels;
             green = green /numberOfSidePixels;
             blue = blue /numberOfSidePixels;
             Globals.RedforSend = red;
             if(serverState==true){
                Client.sendToServer(red,green,blue);
                Client.newMessage();
             }
             Color background = new Color(red, green, blue);
             panel.setBackground(background);
          } catch (AWTException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }

   public MainWindow() {
      mP = new myPrefs();
      mP.init();
      setBounds(100, 100, 175, 165);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setContentPane(contentPane);
      contentPane.setLayout(null);
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBounds(20, 15, 135, 115);
      contentPane.add(panel);
   }

   void saveFrame(JFrame frame) throws IOException {
      String X = String.valueOf(frame.getX());
      String Y = String.valueOf(frame.getY());
      int xPos = frame.getX();
      mP.setMWXPos(xPos);
      int yPos = frame.getY();
      mP.setMWYPos(yPos);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
      System.out.println(
         "componentMoved event from " + e.getComponent().getClass().getName());
      try {
         saveFrame((JFrame) e.getComponent());
      } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
      System.out.println(
         "shown event from " + e.getComponent().getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void switchServerState(){
      serverState = true;
    }
}
```

And Finally the client class that I would like to forward the RGB Data onto a server:

```
package com.lorenjz.jambii;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {
    static String fromUser;
    static Boolean nm = false;
    //static PrintWriter out;
    public void run(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket("LorensMBA.local", 4444);
            // TODO code server for pref from controlGack text input
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: LorensMBA.");
            //System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: LorensMBA.");
            //System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;


        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);

            if(fromServer.equals("Ready to Go")){
                System.out.print("Rockin");
                out.print("myStuff");
                MainWindow.switchServerState();
                }

            if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                break;

            //fromUser = stdIn.readLine();


            //if (nm = true){
            if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);


            }
            nm = false;
            //}
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    }

    public static void sendToServer(int redV, int greenV, int blueV){
        //out.println("Stupid");
        fromUser = "@R"+ redV+",G"+greenV+",B"+blueV;
    }
    public static void newMessage(){
        nm = true;
    }
}


'
```

"if (fromUser != null)" in the client class only seems to be evaluated when I set a breakpoint.  I must be missing something here.  The way that I intend for this to all work out is that the MainWindow will send an RGB value to the client class every time that a screenshot.  Can someone point me in the direction of where I have gone wrong?

Thanks,
Loren

Comment: Why are you dumping a lot of code that is not a real part of your question? You should try to trim it - [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are you sure that the source code you are debugging has the same source code than the compiled code you are running?

Comment: Would you please pin point the line which is getting executed in debug mode only?

Comment: As I see there are Threads involved, so you might me mistaken that the code is not executed. But still reduce the amount of code to actual problem

Comment: here is the line that isn't being run:   `if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);


            }`

Comment: Like people already said in the answers, this is probably due to synchronization problems. You should try searching for "synchronization" and "race conditions" to learn about that topic.

Comment: @Alderath I think you are right.  That's my next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromUser` will be not null only after `sendToServer` has been called. And `sendToServer` is called asynchronously in a thread.

My guess is that when you run the code normally, `sendToServer` has not run yet when your if statement is executed and `fromUser` is still null.

In debug mode, the thread has more time to do its stuff and manages to call `sendToServer` before you reach the if statement.

Also I noticed that you have 2 instances of `MainWindow` - not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense to me.  Thank you!  I need to think about this a little more.

Comment: Vote the question up and accept it.  Thanks aren't the proper currency here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be of **DATA RACE**. So in debug mode when you are setting the debug point the value is set and when you run normally, the value is not set due to RACE.

The variable `fromUser` is the culprit. Try and synchronize it.